# closed:1 search parameter is broken on Area51

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, search

The [search tips](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search) page on Area 51 says, under "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options":

```
proposals that have been closed      closed:1 apples oranges
(or not)                             closed:0 apples oranges
```

However when I actually search for it, [`closed:1`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed:1) does absolutely nothing useful. None of the proposals returned are closed. I have better luck using [`closed:0`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed:0), but it still returns a mix of all kinds of proposals.

It seems like there's some broken logic somewhere, because if I search using a nonexistent parameter like `apples:0` or `apples:1` it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I misunderstood how the feature works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for closed proposal works for me.

[image: screenshot]

The only difference seems to be with unexacting options, for which Stack Overflow uses to search content.

[image: screenshot]

"apples:1" is not understood as search option, and the result page reports, "posts containing 'apples:1'."

The same doesn't happen on Area 51, even searching for "office:1" when there are at least two proposals containing the word "office"; it could mean there aren't proposal containing *office* and *1*, but still, it doesn't seem as Stack Overflow search works.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood how the feature works.